# Can we mix contextmanager decorator with __enter__() and __exit__() methods in another class inside the same with statement?

Tags: python, contextmanager

In python3.8 I'm very familiar with the traditional `__enter__` and `__exit__` magic methods but new to the `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator.  Is it possible to mix the two patterns inside a single `with` statement?

The following (highly contrived) script should explain the problem more clearly.  Is there a definition of `ContextClass.enter_context_function()` and `ContextClass.exit_context_function()` (I imagine something needs to change inside `__init__` as well) that only use the `context_function()` function and makes the unit tests pass?  Or are these patterns mutually exclusive?

```py
import contextlib


NUMBERS = []


@contextlib.contextmanager
def context_function():
    NUMBERS.append(3)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        NUMBERS.append(5)


class ContextClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = NUMBERS
        self.numbers.append(1)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.numbers.append(2)
        self.enter_context_function() # should append 3
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.exit_context_function() # should append 5
        self.numbers.append(6)

    def function_call(self):
        self.numbers.append(4)

    def enter_context_function(self):
        # FIX ME!
        pass

    def exit_context_function(self):
        # FIX ME!
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import unittest

    class TestContextManagerFunctionAndClass(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_context_function_and_class(self):
            with ContextClass() as cc:
                cc.function_call()
            self.assertEqual(NUMBERS, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

    unittest.main()
```

I understand there are better ways to solve a similar problem (specifically rewriting `context_function` as a class with its own `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, but I'm trying to better understand exactly how the contextmanager decorator works.

Comment: Before getting into `ContextClass`, the first problem is that your `context_function` is itself buggy. It's a very common mistake - the `yield` has to be in a `try`, and cleanup has to go in an attached `finally`. Otherwise, the context manager won't run cleanup if an exception occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure how wedded you are with trying to embed one context manager inside another like this. See `contextlib.ExitStack` for a way to manage context managers from inside a `with` statement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I will definitely use that pattern in any production code. This is obviously a toy example and the `yield` statement should still function the same way.

Comment: Whether your second context manager is defined explicitly  as a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods or implicitly via `context manager` doesn't really seem to make a difference in what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No change in the `__init__` is necessary. The manual way which "makes the unit tests pass" would be:

```
def enter_context_function(self):
    self._context_mgr = context_function()
    self._context_mgr.__enter__()

def exit_context_function(self):
    self._context_mgr.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

However, it's kind of missing the point of context-managers. They're intended to be used in a [with-statement](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/).

Also note that, as written, the `NUMBERS.append(5)` line (the "teardown") may not be reached if the code after yielding raises. It should be written like this:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def context_function():
    NUMBERS.append(3)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        NUMBERS.append(5)
```